# Why doesn't file.info() work on a directory I give it?

Tags: r

I cannot get `file.size()` to work on a directory I give it.

I want information about files in a directory other than the working directory.

```
file.info(dir(getwd()))[,c(1, 4)]
# DIRECTORY NAME
dirname <- 'C:/R/R-3.5.1'
# DOESN'T WORK
file.info(dir(dirname))[,c(1, 4)]
# WORK(AROUND?)S
file.info(paste(dirname, dir(dirname), sep = '/' ))[,c(1, 4)]
```

I get the wanted information in the first case but not in the second.

Comment: What do you mean, *"doesn't work"*? Does using `dir(dirname, full.names=TRUE)` fix things? Know that `list.files` (and `dir`) do not return the full path by default, so `dir("../other/path")` happily returns *just the file's names*, not the full path required to get to those files. While I personally find this a horrible default action, it's been there for a long time, and is readily remedied by adding `full.names=TRUE` to the function.

Comment: default actions often seem matters of esthetics; e.g. as a geographer, i think plots of spatial objects should (like plots) display axes by default...thanks for making me read the documentation!

Comment: Does adding `full.names=TRUE` solve the problem?